# Exportar SVGs en una Package y usarlos en un proyecto de React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

tengo 2 proyectos el ce Iconos y el proyecto de React JS limpio para consumir los iconos de la librería.

estoy exportando ficheros SVG desde una la librería de iconos para NPM que he creado y la exportación la tengo en el index.js

```
import React from "react";

export { ReactComponent as IconAdd } from "./add.svg";
```

El proyecto de la librería de iconos tiene la siguiente estructura.

**Estructura del Proyecto**: IconsLib

```
-- node_modules
-- add.svg
-- index.js
-- package.json
-- webpack.config.js
```

Ahora me voy al proyecto de React y con yarn link, linkeo la librería con el proyecto y funciona perfectamente, voy a mostrar el resultado de lo que me llegue IconAdd al proyecto de React JS con el siguiente código.

```
import React from "react";

import * as all from "cecoicons";
console.log(all);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Iconos</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Y el resultado del console.log(all) es el siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado del Icono es undefined, alguien sabe como solucionar este error para que me devuelva el SVG ?

Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: ¿tienes en tu `webpack.config.js` configurado para soportar la carga de archivos svg?¿de qué manera lo tienes hecho? ¿cuál módulo estás usando para cargar este formato de archivo? ¿versión?

Comment: He realizado la siguiente configuración en webpack que esta indicada en la siguiente url. https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/using-svg-files-in-react/228005

Comment: Sin saber lo que estas exportando en el archivo "add.svg" y sin ver la configuración del "webpack.config" es complicado darte una respuesta clara, por favor actualice su pregunta para poder actualizar mi respuesta con una solución. Por otro lado, si quieres manejar "SVG" en linea debes instalar un loader por ejemplo "react-svg-loader".